# Почему при вводе чисел в input type number атрибуты max и min не работают?

Tags: html

```html
     <input type="number" max="50" class="height_o oskh form-control">
```

Ну вот вроде как надо, если переключать стрелочками - всё нормально, но если в ручную то просто сохраняется число даже больше чем max. Та же проблема с min

Comment: Потому что так работает инпут, иначе он не работает. Если вы хотите реально запретить ввод чисел больше указанного максимума придется использовать JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал на jquery как-то так:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.oskh').change(function(){
  if (+$(this).attr('max') < $(this).val()) {
   $(this).val($(this).attr('max'));
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" max="25" class="width_o oskh form-control">
```

Answer (score 3):

Проблема, которую вы описываете, кроется в браузере, используемым вами. Я скопировал ваш код, добавил кнопку подтверждения и сохранил в html -файл. У меня, в браузере Mozilla Firefox, при вводе с клавиатуры числа больше, чем 50, поле ввода выделятся красным, и подтвердить отправку формы невозможно. В Google Chrome и Opera ситуация аналогичная. Вероятно, дело в проблеме с поддержкой HTML5 у вашего браузера.

Как ведут себя разные браузеры, у меня на компьютере:

Mozilla Firefox:

[image: Firefox]

Opera:

[image: Opera]

Google Chrome:

[image: Google Chrome]

В любом случае, введенное число стоит проверять на стороне серевера. Если вы хотите быть полностью уверены, что проверка поля работает, имеет смысл использовать JS-скрипт, выполняющий эту задачу

Comment: Спасибо, я просто не использую форму, мне надо просто инпут. Задачу реализовал через jquery

Answer (score 0):

Может кому пригодится банально вписать required в input тогда начнет требовать ввести число и минимум что Вы вписали

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).